# Does OpenCL support a randomly accessed global queue buffer?

Tags: c, kernel, opencl

I am writing a kernel which processes combinatorial data. Because these sorts of problems generally have a large problem space, where most of the processed data is junk, is there a way I could do the following:

(1) If the calculated data passes some sort of condition, it is put onto a global output buffer.

(2) Once the output buffer is full, the data is sent back to the host

(3) The host takes a copy of the data from the buffer and clears it

(4) Then creates a new buffer to be filled by the GPU

For simplicity, this example could be stated as a selective inner product and I mean that by

```
__global int buffer_counter; // Counts 

void put_onto_output_buffer(float value, __global float *buffer, int size)
{
    // Put this value onto the global buffer or send a signal to the host
}

__kernel void
inner_product(
    __global const float *threshold,       // threshold
    __global const float *first_vector,    // 10000 float vector
    __global const float *second_vector,   // 10000 float vector
    __global float *output_buffer,         // 100 float vector
    __global const int *output_buffer_size // size of the output buffer -- 100
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    float value = first_vector[id] * second_vector[id];
    if (value >= threshold[0])
        put_onto_output_buffer(value, output_buffer, output_buffer_size[0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the frequency of output. If it is high frequency (a work item writes output more often than not) then `buffer_counter` will be a source of contention and will cause slow downs (also, by the way, it will need to be updated using atomic methods, which is why it's slow). It this case you're better off just always writing output and sort through the real ones later.

On the other hand, if writing output is fairly infrequent, then using an atomic position indicator makes good sense. The majority of work items will do their computation, decide they have no output, and retire. Only the infrequent ones that have output will contend over the atomic output position index, serially increment it, and write their output at their unique location. Your output memory will compactly contain the results (in no particular order so store the work item ID if you care).

Again, do read up on atomics because the index needs to be atomic.

Comment: How can I make multiple reads from the buffer within the host?

Comment: You can read the buffer as often as you want, but the host has to map it (using `clEnqueueMapBufer`) to get a pointer to it, and you can't enqueue any kernels using it while the host has it mapped. When you're done reading it (as much as you like), unmap it and then you can run more kernels on it (if you want).

Comment: Also, how does the kernel know when the host has finished reading from the buffer? Or, is this a blocking operation?

Comment: The kernel doesn't "know", you have to sequence it properly: 1. clEnqueueMapBuffer (with blocking), 2. use it as much as you want on the host, 3. clEnqueueUnmapMemObject, 4. clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Comment: Do you know of any examples which do this?