# Why is clEnqueueMapBuffer returning random data?

Tags: c, memory, opencl

I am trying to learn about clEnqueueMapBuffer in OpenCL by writing a kernel which finds the square of values in an input buffer, but only returns two items at a time in the output buffer using clEnqueueMapBuffer. As I understand it, this function returns a pointer in the hosts memory which points to the buffer memory in the device. Then clEnqueueUnmapMemObject must unmap this buffer to allow the kernels to continue their computations. Now, when I call clEnqueueMapBuffer, it is returning random data.

Here is my kernel

```
__kernel void testStream(
    __global int *input_vector,
    __global int *output_vector,
    __global int *mem_flag) // informs the host when the workload is finished
{
    mem_flag[0] = 1;
}
```

and my source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>

#include "utils.h"

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int n = 24;
    int BUFF_SIZE = 2;
    // Input and output vectors
    int num_bytes = sizeof(int) * n;
    int *output_buffer = (int *) malloc(num_bytes);
    int output_buffer_offset = 0;
    int *mapped_data = NULL;
    // use mapped_flag for determining if the job on the device is finished
    int *mapped_flag = NULL;
    int *host_in = (int *) malloc(num_bytes);
    int *host_out = (int *) malloc(num_bytes);
    // Declare cl variables
    cl_mem device_in;
    cl_mem device_out;
    cl_mem device_out_flag;

    // Declare cl boilerplate
    cl_platform_id   platform = NULL;
    cl_device_id     device   = NULL;
    cl_command_queue queue    = NULL;
    cl_context       context  = NULL;
    cl_program       program  = NULL;
    cl_kernel        kernel   = NULL;

    // Located in utils.c -- the source is irrelevant here
    char *kernel_source = read_kernel("kernels/test.cl");

    // Initialize host_in
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        host_in[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // Set up opencl
    cl_int error;
    error   = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    printf("clGetPlatformIDs: %d\n", (int) error);
    error   = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device, NULL);
    printf("clGetDeviceIDs: %d\n", (int) error);
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &error);
    printf("clCreateContext: %d\n", (int) error);
    queue   = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &error);
    printf("clCreateCommandQueue: %d\n", (int) error);
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
        (const char**)&kernel_source, NULL, &error);
    printf("clCreateProgramWithSource: %d\n", (int) error);
    clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "testStream", &error);
    printf("clCreateKernel: %d\n", (int) error);
    // Create the buffers
    device_in = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        num_bytes, NULL, NULL);
    device_out = clCreateBuffer(context,
        CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        sizeof(int) * BUFF_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
    device_out_flag = clCreateBuffer(context,
        CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        sizeof(int) * 2, NULL, NULL);

    // Write the input buffer
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
        queue, device_in, CL_FALSE, 0, num_bytes,
        host_in, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Set the kernel arguments
    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &device_in);
    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &device_out);
    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &device_out_flag);

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of data
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
        (const size_t *) &n, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Map and unmap until the flag is set to true
    int break_flag = 0;
    while(1) {
        // Map the buffers
        mapped_data = (int *) clEnqueueMapBuffer(
            queue, device_out, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0,
            sizeof(int) * BUFF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
        mapped_flag = (int *) clEnqueueMapBuffer(
            queue, device_out_flag, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0,
            sizeof(int) , 0, NULL,NULL, &error);
        // Extract the data out of the buffer
        printf("mapped_flag[0] = %d\n", mapped_flag[0]);
        // Set the break_flag
        break_flag = mapped_flag[0];
        // Unmap the buffers
        error = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, device_out, mapped_data, 0,
            NULL, NULL);
        error = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, device_out_flag, mapped_flag,
            0, NULL, NULL);
        if (break_flag == 1) {break;}
        usleep(1000*1000);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get output similar to

```
clGetPlatformIDs: 0
clGetDeviceIDs: 0
clCreateContext: 0
clCreateCommandQueue: 0
clCreateProgramWithSource: 0
clCreateKernel: 0
mapped_flag[0] = 45366144
mapped_flag[0] = 45366144
mapped_flag[0] = 45366144
mapped_flag[0] = 45366144
mapped_flag[0] = 45366144
```

Why is this happening?

---

### Edit

I am running this code on an HP dm1z with fedora 19 64-bit on the kernel 3.13.7-100.fc19.x86_64. Here is the output from clinfo

```
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices


  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               2
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Device ID:                     4098
  Board name:                    AMD Radeon HD 6310 Graphics
  Device Topology:               PCI[ B#0, D#1, F#0 ]
  Max compute units:                 2
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               256
    Max work items[1]:               256
    Max work items[2]:               256
  Max work group size:               256
  Preferred vector width char:           16
  Preferred vector width short:          8
  Preferred vector width int:            4
  Preferred vector width long:           2
  Preferred vector width float:          4
  Preferred vector width double:         0
  Native vector width char:          16
  Native vector width short:             8
  Native vector width int:           4
  Native vector width long:          2
  Native vector width float:             4
  Native vector width double:            0
  Max clock frequency:               492Mhz
  Address bits:                  32
  Max memory allocation:             134217728
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       128
  Max number of images write arguments:      8
  Max image 2D width:                16384
  Max image 2D height:               16384
  Max image 3D width:                2048
  Max image 3D height:               2048
  Max image 3D depth:                2048
  Max samplers within kernel:            16
  Max size of kernel argument:           1024
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      2048
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     No
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    None
  Cache line size:               0
  Cache size:                    0
  Global memory size:                201326592
  Constant buffer size:              65536
  Max number of constant args:           8
  Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                 32768
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     32
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        1
  Profiling timer resolution:            1
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             No
  Queue properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Platform ID:                   0x00007fd434852fc0
  Name:                      Loveland
  Vendor:                    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.2 
  Driver version:                1214.3
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_atomic_counters_32 cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_amd_image2d_from_buffer_read_only
```

Also, it may be worth noting that when I began playing with OpenCL, I ran a test program to calculate the inner product, but that gave weird results. Initially I though it was an error with the program and forgot about it, but is it possible that the OpenCL implementation is faulty? If it helps, the OpenGL implementation has multiple errors, causing blocks of random data to show up on my desktop background, but this could also be a Linux problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `NULL` as the global work size to your `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` call:

```
// Execute the kernel over the entire range of data
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

If you were checking the error code returned by this call (which you *always* should), you would get the error code corresponding to `CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE` back. You always need to specify a global work size, so your call should look something like this:

```
// Execute the kernel over the entire range of data
size_t global[1] = {1};
error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
// check error == CL_SUCCESS!
```

Your calls to map and unmap buffers are fine; I've tested this code with the above fix and it works for me.

---

Your updated code to fix the above problem looks like this:

```
unsigned int n = 24;
...
// Execute the kernel over the entire range of data
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
    (const size_t *) &n, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

This is not a safe way of passing the global work size parameter to the kernel. As an example, the `unsigned int n` variable might occupy 32 bits, whereas a `size_t` could be 64 bits. This means that when you pass the address of `n` and cast to a `const size_t*`, the implementation will read a 64-bit value, which will encompass the 32 bits of `n` plus 32 other bits that have some arbitrary value. You should either assign `n` to a `size_t` variable before passing it to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, or just change it to be a `size_t` itself.

This may or may not be related to the problems you are having. You could be accidentally launching a *huge* number of work-items for example, which might explain why the code appears to block on the CPU.

Comment: You were correct about the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel not having a bound, but I've fixed this error. Also, both calls of clEnqueueMapBuffer and clEnqueueUnmapMemObject return CL_SUCCESS. But, I'm still receiving garbage data, which is usually -1, but sometimes is some other negative number.

Comment: @user1876508 I've tested this on a bunch of different platforms and it works every time. Can you give us some information about your system - which device, OS, SDK version etc? You could try filling the buffer with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` to see if the problem is the kernel invocation.

Comment: You should be careful with the types, use cl_int for the cl types and try again. (just in case, but i don't see why it should not work)

Comment: @jprice Check out the edits I made, I included information about my OS and the relevant output of clinfo

Comment: @user1876508 Did you try running this on the CPU as well as the GPU? It's entirely possible that this is a bug in the OpenCL implementation, as you are having problems with other programs.

Comment: I can't run it on the CPU. When I call clEnqueueMapBuffer, the program blocks. I am assuming this is because the implementation is calling clEnqueueMapBuffer on the same thread. Is this not suppose to happen?

Comment: @user1876508 `clEnqueueMapBuffer` should block until the mapping operation completes, since you are passing `CL_TRUE` as the third parameter. This potentially indicates that prior commands are still executing (e.g. the kernel). There's one possible explanation for this, which I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few remarks that come to my mind:

- I have the feeling that somehow you think that calling `clEnqueueMapBuffer` will interrupt the execution of the kernel. I don't think this is correct. Once a command is launched for execution it runs until it is completed (or failed...). It is possible for several commands to be launched concurrently, but trying to read some data while a kernel is still processing it will result in undefined behavior. Besides, the way  you create your command queue wouldn't let you run several commands at the same time. You need to use `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` property when creating the queue to allow that.
- I don't know with which global size you call your kernel after the post of @jprice, but except if you execute the kernel with only one workitem you'll have trouble with this kind of statement: `mem_flag[0] = 1;` since all the workitems will write to the same location. (I'm guessing that you posted only a portion of your kernel. Check if you have other statements like that...actually that'd be useful if you post the entire kernel code).
- Since you map and unmap always the same portion of the buffers and always go to check in the first element (of mapped_flag) and since the kernel has completed its computation at that moment (see first point), at least it is normal that you always have the same value read.

Comment: You are also correct about my assumption. I was given this strategy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246965/does-opencl-support-a-randomly-accessed-global-queue-buffer/22271165?noredirect=1#comment35437551_22271165.

Comment: That was my comment you linked to but I never implied you could map the buffer _while the GPU was using it_. You seem to think that the CPU and GPU could be sharing the memory and communicating through it but that is not how OpenCL works. It is asynchronous and memory can only be used by one side at a time. (That is, until OpenCL 2.0 with SVM and atomic memory access)